# Error: java.lang.arrayindexoutofboundsexception:15

Tags: java

**En mi programa marca este error y no se donde esta el problema.**

Lo que intento hacer es generar 45 números de un entero y un decimal, se guarden en 3 arreglos de 15 elementos cada uno y se genere otro arreglo de solo 3 elementos donde se guarden la sumatoria de cada uno de los arreglos y al final mostrar los 4 arreglos en 4 columnas consecutivas.

Este es mi programa:

```
    StdIn in = new StdIn ();  
    float[] PC = new float [15];  
    float[] SC = new float [30];
    float[] TC = new float [46];    
    int A, B, C;  
    float S;  
    for (A = 1 ; A < 15 ; A++)
    {
        System.out.println ("Primer Columna");
        System.out.print (A + "\tNumero: ");
        PC [A] = in.readFloat ();
    }
    for (B = 15 ; B < 30 ; B++)
    {
        System.out.println ("Segunda Columna");
        System.out.print (B + "\tNumero:\t");
        SC [B] = in.readFloat ();
    }
    for (C = 30 ; C < 46 ; C++)
    {
        System.out.println ("Tercer Columna");
        System.out.print (C + "\tNumero:\t");
        TC [C] = in.readFloat ();
    }
    System.out.println ("Primer Columna" + PC [A]);
    System.out.println ("Segunda Columna" + SC [B]);
    System.out.println ("Tercer COlumna" + TC [C]);
    S = PC [A] + SC [B] + TC [C];
    System.out.println ("Sumatoria de las 3 columnas" + S);
    } 
}
```

Y el renglón que marca "mal" después de ese error es esta:

```
System.out.println ("Primer Columna" + PC [A]);
```

Comment: ahi lo que dice es que estas tratando de acceder a una posicion de un array que no existe, por ende ser "desborda" intenta con System.out.println ("Primer Columna" + PC [A-1]);

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Fijate que A tiene el valor que termino en el for. Que estas tratando de hacer? asi no vas a imprimir toda una columna. y tampoco vas a sumar asi todos los valores.

Comment: @srJJ lo cambie añadiendo [A-1] pero en el resultado final me presenta 0.0  
 System.out.println ("Primer Columna" + PC[A-1]);    
        System.out.println ("Segunda Columna" + SC[B-1]);    
        System.out.println ("Tercer COlumna" + TC[C-1]);  
        S = PC[A-1] + SC[B-1] + TC[C-1];  
        System.out.println ("Sumatoria de las 3 columnas" + S);

Comment: @Camila te sugiero leer este articulo : https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3583/cómo-hacer-preguntas-de-manera-correcta-y-evitar-que-te-la-cierren  de como hacer buenas preguntas , porque te lo aseguro esta pregunta no tiene nada que ver con stackoverflow, te sugiero buscar en google :) y si no sabes como se crean las buenas preguntas aqui, te recomiendo leer el tour : es.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: @Camila que has intentado hacer? solo vez el error? no has intentador ir a la documentacion antes? quiza sea un problema basico de sintaxis

Comment: @simon Lo que intento hacer es generar 45 numeros de un entero y un decimal, se guarden en 3 arreglos de 15 elementos cada uno y se genere otro arreglo de solo 3 elementos donde se guarden la sumatoria de cada uno de los arreglos y al final mostrar los 4 arreglos en 4 columnas consecutivas

Comment: @Camila ahi si el problema mas seguro es de logica, explicanos bien, que es lo que quieres conseguir

Comment: @Camila ahora ya tienes lo que quieres hacer,te sugiero agregarlo a la pregunta.

Comment: @Camila, y tienes que imprimir todos los 15 registro de cada arreglo ?

Comment: @ srJJ Básicamente quiero presentar 45 números, dividirlos en 3 arreglos, en otro arreglo sumar los 3 arreglos anteriores y presentar esos 4 arreglos en 4 columnas

Answer (score 0):

aqui te dejo otro modo de hacerlo... con dos ciclos uno llena y el otro muestra

```
StdIn in = new StdIn ();  
    float[] PC = new float [15];  
    float[] SC = new float [30];
    float[] TC = new float [46];    
    int A, B, C;  
    float S;  

    for (j=1; j <= 45 ; j++) {

        if (j <=15 ) {
            System.out.println ("Primer Columna");
            System.out.print (j + "\tNumero: ");
            PC [j] = in.readFloat ();
        }
        else if (j > 15 && j <= 30) {
            System.out.println ("Segunda Columna");
            System.out.print (j + "\tNumero:\t");
            SC [j] = in.readFloat ();
        }
        else if (j > 30 && j <= 45) {
            System.out.println ("Tercer Columna");
            System.out.print (j + "\tNumero:\t");
            TC [j] = in.readFloat ();
        }
    }
//aqui se muestran y se suman todas las filas de los arreglos


for (j = 1; j < PC.length ; j++) {
        System.out.println ("Primer Columna" + PC [j]);
        System.out.println ("Segunda Columna" + SC [j]);
        System.out.println ("Tercer COlumna" + TC [j]);
        S = PC [j] + SC [j] + TC [j];
        System.out.println ("Sumatoria de las 3 columnas" + S);
    }

}
```

espero te sirva y la marque como resulta para que otros se ayuden con esta... NiceCode By: JJ